# How to import XLSX data as integers?

Tags: import, excel

I am importing simple 0s and 1s array from Excel

```
myDep = Import[
FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "dependencies.xlsx"}], {"Sheets",
"Data"}]
```

All good

```
{{1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 
0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.}, {1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.}, {0., 
0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}}
```

But I get it imported as Real, and being a newbie I cannot find the way to import is as Integer. Any simple way to import it as *Integer* numbers? Sorry for such a mundane question.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: You may be interested in `Rationalize`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Konstantin, Welcome to MSE. If the data values are either 0 or 1, you can use `IntegerPart` to convert after importing.

```
IntegerPart[{{1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 
0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.}, {1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.}}]

(* {{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1,
   1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me
    `myDep = IntegerPart[
  Import[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], 
     "dependencies.xlsx"}], {"Sheets", "Data"}]]`

Comment: That's great. Would you mind accepting my answer.